# How can I see the status of the messages in a batch from Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new in the field of Azure. I am testing the functionality called "Send, receive, an batch process messages in Azure Logic Apps". This is the link of the documentation:

[Batches in Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-batch-process-send-receive-messages)

I could do everything what in that tutorial exists and it works. I created a batch called "Test" (This is the Batch name). My question is: Is there a monitor in Azure portal where I can see which messages were created in that batch from the "batch sender" and therefore see the current status of these messages?.

In other words I would like to see which message was already processed by the "batch receiver" and which ones still remain to be processed. I would like to know if I can monitor this batch that I created.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to see which message was already processed by the "batch receiver"

As of now there is no way we can alone monitor the batch process but Here is one of the workarounds for this, You can add a compose connector and add all the parameters as per the requirement.

Here is my logic app workflow
[image]
So each time this logic app gets triggered by the batch process we can check all the properties that we have mentioned for that particular message.
Here is the sample output:
[image]

You can check the processed message by the "batch receiver" from the run history of the logic app.

[image]

> and therefore see the current status of these messages?.

You can monitor this from Azure Monitor logs. which gives number runs that are running, succeeded and failed.
[image]

> and which ones still remain to be processed.

This depends on from where you are trying to send the messages

You can follow this document for [Monitor logic apps by using Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics)

Comment: Tks @SwethaKandikonda-MT for this workarround. From your answer what I understood there is not a Monitor to see the messages in a particular Batch in Azure Portal. I know how to check each run in Azure. However, I want to check which messages were created in the batch from the Batch-sender before the batch-receiver starts and also which messages where processed succesfull and with error by the batch-receiver. That is why this workarround is not what I am looking for, but anyway tks for your time and support, I really appreciate it.